# WPF Create Label and Path in one Object

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to create class with Label and Path as one single object
so I did this:

```
class MyLine : Shape
{
    Point p1,p2;
    Label lbl;
    Path arrow;

    public void AddToCanvas(Canvas x)
    {
        x.Children.Insert(0, lbl);
        x.Children.Insert(0, arrow);

        updateLBL(); 
        updateArrow();
    }
    public void RemoveFromCanvas(Canvas x)
    {
        x.Children.Remove(lbl);
        x.Children.Remove(arrow);
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

It's work fine but I can't remove MyLine from canvas as single object,I have to remove Path then Label.

```
class MainClass
{
    // ... code

    public void DrawMyLine(MyLine m)
    {
        _Canvas.Children.Add(m);  // this work fine
    }

    object selectdeobject;

    public void CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       selectdeobject = _Canvas.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(_Canvas)) as FrameworkElement;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
       if (selectdeobject != null)
       {
           if (selectdeobject is MyLine) // this always false
           {
                MyLine t = selectdeobject as MyLine;
                t.RemoveFromCanvas(_Canvas);
           }
           else if(selectdeobject is Path)
           {
                _Canvas.Children.Remove((selectdeobject as Path)) // this delete only the Path and keep the Label
           }
           else if(selectdeobject is Label)
           {
                _Canvas.Children.Remove((selectdeobject as Label)) // this delete only the Label and keep the Path
           }
        }
    }
}
```

any help to make the selected object act like one single object ?

Comment: Where are you getting `selectedobject` from?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add this: selectdeobject = _Canvas.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(_Canvas)) as FrameworkElement;

Comment: Well, I'm guessing its drilling down to what you *actually* selected. Hard to say for sure, as this kind of UI manipulation isn't my forte. Thank you for clarifying though.